# How can I programatically get the cart's dollar sum of drupal commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce, theming, debugging

For future users `<?php echo  '$' . number_format(( $total['amount'] /100),2); ?>` is how.

---

Following this guide http://kahthong.com/2012/08/programmatically-show-number-items-drupal-commerce-shopping-cart I got the cart item total using

```
<?php
global $user;
$quantity = 0;
$order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
if ($order) {
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
    $line_items = $wrapper->commerce_line_items;
    $quantity = commerce_line_items_quantity($line_items, commerce_product_line_item_types());
    $total = commerce_line_items_total($line_items);
    $currency = commerce_currency_load($total['currency_code']);
}
print format_plural($quantity, '1 item', '@count items');
?>
```

however when I try to get the dollar total using `<?php print $total; ?>`, it just returns 'Array'.

I used Devel on the page, but the cart is just a bunch of markup in `['content']['system_main']['main']['#markup']`. What I want is `<span class="line-item-total-raw">$106.00</span>`, is there a way I can grab that class specifically with php somehow? Or maybe there's another way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have it already.  That call to "commerce_line_items_total" returns the array:

```
return array('amount' => $total, 'currency_code' => $currency_code);
```

Thus you should have the total price at $total['amount'] since you already have $total['currency_code']